# rename(1) a set of files beyond the current directory

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, bash, rename

The `rename` command in Ubuntu 12.04 (manpage says it's part of perl v5.14.2 2012-03-23) works well in a single directory, but I want to use it on subdirectories too (or, more generally, on a list of files that is the output of another command, via backquotes).  For example, I'd expect

```
rename "s/ /-/g"  `find .`
```

to change all spaces to dashes in all filenames below the current dir.  But this command does nothing.

(**Edit**: changed `rename -n` to `rename`.  That option's good for safely experimenting, but only a distraction here.)

The backquotes are not at fault, because replacing `find .` with e.g. `echo */*` works.

First doing `find . > foo`, and then replacing `find .` with `cat foo`, does nothing.

Even collapsing the list of files into one line, by replacing `find .` with `find . | tr -d '\n'`, does nothing.

Which element is at fault?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will not work:

```
rename 's/ /-/g'  `find .`
```

After running the find command, the shell does word splitting on the results.  Consequently, no file name with spaces survives in tact: it is split up into pieces.

You can avoid this by using:

```
rename 's/ /-/g'  */*
```

In this form of the command, the shell does not do word splitting and your `rename` will succeed.  This form works even for file names with spaces, tabs, or any other difficult characters.

Alternatively, use find's `-exec`:

```
find . -name '* *' -exec rename 's/ /-/g' {} +
```

This form will work with file names having spaces, tabs, or any other difficult characters.

#### Demonstration

To see what goes wrong, let's create a file with spaces

```
$ touch "a b c"
$ find .
.
./a b c
```

To clarify what goes on, let's create a function to put each argument it sees inside double quotes and display it:

```
$ display() { printf '"%s"\n' "$@"; }
```

Now, we can use `display` to see what happens when we run `find .`:

```
$ display `find .`
"."
"./a"
"b"
"c"
```

This shows word splitting in action.  The file name `a b c` was split into three separate words.

Comment: "in tact": I see what you did there :-)

Comment: Whitespace in filenames is just one example:  a better one might be `s/png/jpg/`.  So this *general* answer reduces to the workaround of replacing backquotes with `find ... -exec rename ...`, or `find ... | xargs rename ...`.  So I still wonder why backquotes fail.

Comment: @CamilleGoudeseune "So I still wonder why backquotes fail." It does not have anything to do with which substitute command is used.  It is because filenames with white space on the command line are subject to word splitting.  Otherwise, it works.

Comment: Correct.  Whitespace in filenames is the **only** problem, after all.  I made a better test case from scratch, and, yes, backquotes work.  Sorry for wasting your time.